# Difference between intent-filter and deepLink tag for creating deepLink in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the Difference between intent-filter and deepLink tag for creating deep links in Android?
Do both serve the same purpose or different use cases?

intent-filter example reference: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

example reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/deep-link#implicit